# How to loop a string as key value pairs

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, loops, for-loop

I want to loop a string as a key/value pairs. The data is given me as a string(i am using the jstorage plugin).

I have tried to split the string as an array, but it is not returning the right key/values.

Example

```
 "color":"#000000", "font":"12px", "background":"#ffffff",
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Safely turning a JSON string into an object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015/safely-turning-a-json-string-into-an-object)

Comment: So you have a string like `'"color":"#000000", "font":"12px", "background":"#ffffff",'`?

Comment: jStorage lets you store arbitrary objects as values, so you shouldn't be in this position to begin with. You should change your sentence "The data is given me as a string" to "____ gives me the data as a string", and then fix whatever ____ is!

Comment: Please show the code you've tried already.

Comment: See below for the solution. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you always get the string like that, i.e. keys and values in double quotes, you can add `{...}` to the string and [parse it as JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464354/parse-json-string):

```
// remove trailing comma, it's not valid JSON
var obj = JSON.parse('{' + str.replace(/,\s*$/, '') + '}');
```

If not, splitting the string is easy as well, assuming that `,` and `:` cannot occur in keys or values:

```
var obj = {},
    parts = str.replace(/^\s+|,\s*$/g, '').split(',');

for(var i = 0, len = parts.length; i < len; i++) {
    var match = parts[i].match(/^\s*"?([^":]*)"?\s*:\s*"?([^"]*)\s*$/);
    obj[match[1]] = match[2];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what i am looking for the whole night.

Answer (score 0):

You need to evaluate it into a JavaScript object. Provided you trust the source, or can validate the content, you can do this:

```
s = document.createElement('script')
s.type='text/javascript';
s.innerHTML = 'var data = {'+ text + '}';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
```